# how to create wordpress fixed nav bar with popup menu?

Tags: wordpress

#### Hi Friends,

how to create wordpress fixed nav bar with popup       menu Eg..(https://surgeryxchange.com)[image]

Comment: Could you explain some more please? Where not there to code and style the menu you want :)

Comment: static fixed nav bar, dynamic menu should be popup .(https://surgeryxchange.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used same css and javascript files.
I have created custom header and it working properly